# Send and Receive message not display in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I develop sms app using smsManager. I send and receive sms successfully but send and receive message not display in listview. I use listview adapter for display message in listview but nothing.
Listview custom adapter code below:

```
 public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                final String wordslist) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);

        }

        TextView txt_worditem;

        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            try {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.worditem, parent, false);
                txt_worditem = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.main_txt_worditem);
                //txt_worditem.setText(wordslist.get(position));
                                // txt_worditem.setBackgroundColor(55 + AppSettings.bck_color);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            }

            return row;
        }
    }
```

I set `MyCustomAdapter` in `onCreate()` method:

```
   MyCustomAdapter mdp = new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.worditem, wordslist);
   lv.setAdapter(mdp);
   lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Everything fine in code no error occurred but send and receive message not display in listview. Please help me for displaying message in listview.

Comment: Do you notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter when a new item is added to the list?

Comment: How to use notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: When the ArrayList, or the collection you are using, has changed its content, for the adapter to make the changes visible, you have to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In your MyCustomAdapter constructor

```
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                final String wordslist) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);

}
```

`final String wordslist` should be `List<String> wordsList`.

your super call should be

```
super(context, textViewResourceId, wordsList);
```

So overall it will look like this

```
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> wordsList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, wordsList);

}
```

Comment: i use messages[0].getMessageBody() and messages[0].getOriginatingAddress () for receive sms and phone number. How to set sms and number to list item.

Comment: i am use string for sms recieve and send. So not possible to String value set to List<String>.